# Plotly button based on filtered dataframe

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to add a button to a timeline graph in plotly. The button should graph the filtered version of the original dataframe.  The code I am trying and is not working is as follows:

This is the code I tried and It is not working. In fact the button is doing nothing:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
tasks = [
    {'task': 'Task 1', 'start_date': '2024-01-01', 'end_date': '2024-01-10', 'flag': 'special'},
    {'task': 'Task 1.1', 'start_date': '2024-01-01', 'end_date': '2024-01-05', 'flag': 'normal'},
    {'task': 'Task 1.2', 'start_date': '2024-01-05', 'end_date': '2024-01-10', 'flag': 'normal'},
    {'task': 'Task 2', 'start_date': '2024-01-10', 'end_date': '2024-01-25', 'flag': 'special'},
    {'task': 'Task 2.1', 'start_date': '2024-01-10', 'end_date': '2024-01-12', 'flag': 'normal'},
    {'task': 'Task 2.2', 'start_date': '2024-01-12', 'end_date': '2024-01-25', 'flag': 'normal'}
    # Add more tasks as needed
]

# Convert data to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(tasks)

df2 = df[df['flag'] == 'special']

# Create timeline plot with Plotly Express
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start='start_date', x_end='end_date', y='task', color='flag')

# The problem is here how the button is added
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[
    dict(type='buttons',
         showactive=True,
         buttons=[
             dict(label='df',
                  method='restyle',
                  args=[{'data_frame':'df'}]),
             dict(label='df2',
                  method='restyle',
                  args=[{'data_frame':'df2'}])
         ])
])

fig.update_yaxes(categoryorder='category descending')

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

Could you please help me? Is there a way to make it work?

Thanks